# How to open a frmWindow a second time wothout refreshing a grid in the first one?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, showdialog

I have a Window with a Grid that is making a select from MySQL, and using the `.Show()` function insted of `ShowDialog()`.
I can open the same window a second time to have two instances of the same window.

Now, when i open the second instance the grid populates with the new selection also in the first window. How can I make the window to open the second time  without refresing the grid in it again in the first one?

Comment: maybe there is a bug in your code. can you provide a code sample that recreates the effect?

Comment: Hard to tell without a code sample. But: are you sure you aren't binding both grids to the same data source? If the data source encapsulates filtering, it would be logical for both grids to refresh and show the same data.

Comment: Are you refrencing the Form.Grid directly from a source outwith the form?

Comment: there is only one grid, that is boud to a datasource... but from the second win it refreshes in the first window..  how can I chenge to refresh only in the second one?

Comment: Are you refrencing the Form.Grid directly from a source outwith the form No the source is a datatable defined in a .xsd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a new instance of the same form, based on the variable "myForm" from different locations, you are in effect going to "refresh" both forms.

One way to get around this is to create a second variable instance of your frmMain in a seperate function.  (ie... not good at VB at all, so forgive my VB programming skills.)

In one function:

```
Dim myForm AS New formMain()
myForm.Show();
```

In a second function

```
Dim frmTwo AS New frmMain()
frmTwo.Show();
```

Then you just make your calls to frmTwo, which is the second form opened.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Form.Show is a simple function that just tells a form to unhide, it might be using the same instance hence it refreshed both.

Try this instead:

```
   Dim myForm As New frmMain() // Change frmMain to your forms name
   myForm.Show()
```